# Inductor - capacitor filter, load disconnected

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, filter

I'm designing a power supply filter based on inductor - capacitor topology, as shown below.

[image: LC filter]

However, when the load is suddenly disconnected, a high current starts flowing through the capacitor, as the inductor tries to keep the current constant. What are the ways to prevent this? I'm thinking about adding a short circuit protection across the capacitor.

---

Suggested solution: flyback diode across the inductor.

It would be forward biased during periods marked in red below - the current then is not flowing through the diodes.

The current won't flow through any diode - when input voltage is low - say 0, then the inductor is maintaining the current, which flows through the load, capacitor and diode itself.

[image: forward bias]

I performed a simulation in Falstad, the diode conducts high current.

[image]

And in LTspice, which shows high current.

[image]

Comment: If load is disconnected, the energy from the inductor is transferred to the capacitor resulting in high current flow.

Comment: The problem, I suppose, is that the LC by itself is underdamped without the load. It may be detrimental to circuit performance, but if you are able to add damping anywhere it may stabilize the voltage response. Could be in series with the cap, or the inductor. shunt resistance could stabilize too, but I assume that is a no-go. Maybe a shunt RC could help.

Comment: You simulation appears to have a load of 500u\$\Omega\$, and in another shot (same simulation?), you have a sine wave input of 100V with 0 impedance. Are these figures what you want?  If it were not for the 100V, I would say you were designing a utility substation. In a more likely scenario, the current through your inductor would be much smaller. Apart from that, one way to dissipate unwanted AC from your filter is to add in parallel with your cap, a second cap in series with a resistor.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what is the expected load current and the approximate DC voltage at the capacitor?

Comment: Load current 3 kA and capacitor voltage about 1,5 V

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a TVS diode across the capacitor after the inductor which turns on after a certain voltage is reached. Size the diode higher than the voltage that the load will see (so it doesn't turn on during normal use, and only turns on in the event of an over voltage condition).

[image]
Source: http://www.flexautomotive.net/EMCFLEXBLOG/post/2016/09/15/automotive-centralized-load-dump-test-requirments

Another thing you could try is a flyback diode across the inductor
[image]

The diode conducts nA in simulation and is negligible.
[image: ![enter image description here]]

Comment: Yes, I agree that this could work, but before the voltage across the capacitor reaches the TVS activation voltage the capacitor gets damaged due to overcurrrent.

Comment: Flyback diode shorts during normal operation

Comment: I don't see how the flyback diode can become forward biased in normal operation. Maybe I am just not thinking about it correctly.

Comment: How can it become biased? the current through L1 can only go from the diodes to the load (D1 and D2 can only conduct if current is flowing to the load). The only time the flyback diode will conduct is during flyback operation where the load is disconnected (or if the breakdown of D1 or D2 should happen which it should never reach that condition in a properly designed circuit).

Comment: I added a simulation in my original post. The current flowing through the diode is comparable to the load current.

Comment: The simulation is using falstad (which has a sub par solver) with no parasitics and not simulating a real world circuit, the inductors you are using above are superconducting. The diodes are probably ideal and have no curve, use a real model. Put in some real world values for components that can be purchased (or built). For example, at a minimum any inductor will have pFs or parallel capacitance and at least 0.1mΩ or 1mΩ of  series resistance. You should also put in some ESR for the capacitor and some inductance.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think it would diametrically change the situation, the current will still flow through the diode.

Comment: Funny, because I can get the exact same simulation in falstad working in spice... or just ignore what I know. I have built and tested AC  power supplies before.

Comment: Build the circuit in real life and measure the voltage across the inductor, it should be quite low. I also think that the simulation is incorrectly reporting the overvoltage and current that can be achieved from switching the inductor off (parasitics make a big difference there also).

Comment: Could you please post the falstad simulation? If there's no forward bias, then what's causing the flow through the inductor when supply is low (zero)?

Comment: I don't work with falstad, the problem is the inductor is superconducting and giving results that are not physical.

Comment: Ok I see. But why I’m getting high current also in spice? (Added new simulation in the first post)

Comment: Because you did not add parasitics.

Comment: Yes it is important to use realistic values for components and voltages and also to include series resistance in inductor and capacitor models. Otherwise you can get transient results that are completely impossible in the real world.